# soapUI works fine but gets soapenv:Server.generalException error

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, soapui

I am using **soapUI 32 bit** on **Windows 64 bit** pc. It works fine but when I create a soap project and send a web request I get this error:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><soapenv:Fault> <faultcode>soapenv:Server.generalException</faultcode> <faultstring>java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.jpam.Pam; nested exception is: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.jpam.Pam</faultstring><detail><ns1:hostname xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">CO10-SST01</ns1:hostname> </detail></soapenv:Fault></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Is this problem related with the JRE or JDK versions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You get

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.jpam.Pam;
```

[JPam](http://jpam.sourceforge.net/) is a standard security architecture used on Linux, Mac OS X, Solaris, HP-UX and other Unix systems.

If your web service or soapUi need JPam for installation instructions [please check this link](http://jpam.sourceforge.net/documentation/getting_started.html), but I see Windows isn't support.

Could you checked soapUi 64 bit? If you get same error I think you need check what using this lib.